# Quicksight "manage data sets" displays no data sets even though I set some up and they are in use

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I established some QuickSight data sets (basic RDS replica connections). Data is flowing into QuickSight and users have created dashboards using SPICE. At some point - all of these data sets disappeared from my view.

Reproduction steps are simply:
`QuickSight landing page -> Manage Data -> Your Data sets is empty.`

I am an IAM user, if that matters.

Comment: Do users in your organization use the QuickSight SDK APIs? The only thing I could see doing this would be the update permissions APIs. Can you still see the data _sources_?

Comment: I have done some testing with the SDK (creating a dummy group but did not add my user). Removed that test group, same issue. I created a new ADMIN account for myself using email...I can see the sample SPICE data sets but still none of my organization's. Furthermore, if I select "All Dashboards" I can see a dashboard and look at the data sources and see they are coming from RDS. But I do not see any of the sources themselves. I can add new data sources, I think, but not view existing. Very, very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this as a user with `AdministratorAccess` using the AWS CLI (https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/index.html).

First [listing the datasources](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/list-data-sources.html):

`aws quicksight list-data-sources --aws-account-id 1234567890`

Then [describing](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-data-source.html) each of them:

`aws quicksight describe-data-set --data-set-id aaaabbbb-ccc-ddd-eee-11111111 --aws-account-id 1234567890`

It seems there is more available here as an IAM administrator than via the console.